# Create multiple plots based on the entry of another column

Tags: python, plot, graphics

I want to create a loop to plot the data in column "B" based on the value in column "A", so one plot for the "B" data in 2020 and a separate one for the data in 2021.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 10 |
| 2020 | 15 |
| 2021 | 18 |
| 2021 | 20 |
| 2021 | 15 |

What i tried so far, but didnt really work out, since plots are just empty:

```
for A, data in df.groupby('A'):
    plt.plot(df.query('A=="{A}"')['B'], label=A)
    plt.savefig('plot_{}.png'.format(A))
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly what you want to do with this df, here is a possible solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = [[2020, 10], [2020, 15], [2021, 18], [2021, 20], [2021, 15]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])

groupby = df.groupby('A')
dates = list(df['A'].unique())

for i in dates:
    group1 = groupby.get_group(i)
    x = group1['A']
    y = group1['B']
    plt.figure(figsize=(18,14))
    plt.scatter(x, y, c ="blue", s=40)
    plt.xlabel('B')
    plt.ylabel(i)
    plt.show()
```

Hope this helps!